# SQL Server CE 4.0 with multiple connections across seperate processes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce-4

Is this possible? I have a web application the uses EF code-first and SQL Server CE 4.0.

Can I have a Winforms app that also uses the same `.sdf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can - as long as everything runs on the same computer, and the database file resides on  local disk.